# Is there an equivalent way to use Fluent Assertions as replacement for Moq.Verify?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, fluent-assertions

We use the Moq framework and FluentAssertions in oue tests. At the moment we use both to do our assertions, e.g. we will verify that methods etc. on mocks are called. It would be great, if we could do this within the FluentAssertions framework as we like to do multiple assertions in one method and often use either FluentAssertions `And()` to chain these assertions together or the assertion scope so that the results of all assertions can be seen in one go.

So my question is: Is there some way we could be doing this in the current fluent assertions framework, so we could either use the `And()` or the assertion scope to work with it?

Or is there away that these verify actions can be used to work thise way in some wrapped form?

Support out of the box would be great.

Comment: Please post some code because your question is too hard to understand just like that

Answer (score 0):

To include a call to Verify in an AssertionScope, you could do something like:

```
Action verifyAction = () => myMock.VerifyAll();
verifyAction.Should().NotThrow();
```

This could then be used in an AssertionScope. It's not very clean in terms of how the error would be logged, but it would achieve the aim of wrapping multiple calls to Moq Verify in a Fluent Assertions AssertionScope.